# Why does knex.ref return `not-a-function` error?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js, ref

I have a hard time to use ref in knex - because no matter what I do it returns `ref is not a function`.

knex.js-File

```js
const database = knex({
    client: "pg",
    connection: connectionString,
    pool: {
        min: 2,
        max: 10,
    },
    debug: isDevelopment,
}).withSchema("appschema");

module.exports = database;
```

Example 1:

```js
const database = require("../knex.js");

async function getResults() {
   const result = await database.from("table").select(database.ref("id").as("table_id"); <- ref not a function
}
```

Example 2:

```js
const database = require("../knex.js");
const knex = require("knex");

async function getResults() {
   const result = await database.from("table").select(knex.ref("id").as("table_id"); <- ref not a function
}
```

Example 3:

```js
const database = require("../knex.js");
const Knex = require("knex");

async function getResults() {
   const result = await database.from("table").select(Knex.ref("id").as("table_id"); <- ref not a function
}
```

I would expect, at least from the documentation and some examples in the web, that it should be used like the first example.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.withSchema("appschema")` should not be used here, because then you don't get the knex-object. Instead you get a knex query builder.